# Change in code from excel 2010 to excel 2013 on .move

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I had code that worked perfectly in excel 2010- having upgraded to Office 365 and updating, the code now gives an error on the Move" method and then an "out of memory error" when running.  The code is as follows:

```
  For i = 1 To PrincipalNumber
   If PrincipalList(i) <> PrincipalList(i - 1) Then
   If InStr(1, PrincipalList(i), "(") > 0 Then
    PrincipalName = Left(PrincipalList(i), 25) & 0
   Else
    PrincipalName = Left(PrincipalList(i), 25)
   End If
   namefile = DirectoryName & "\" & PrincipalName & "Full2"
   'Set sheets to save
   sheet5save = PrincipalName & " NPT"
   sheet6save = PrincipalName & " NP"
   sheet7save = PrincipalName & "J"
   sheet8save = PrincipalName & " JOBS"
   CurrentWorkBook.Sheets(Array(sheet5save, sheet6save, sheet7save, sheet8save)).Move
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs namefile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
   ActiveWorkbook.Close
   CurrentWorkBook.Activate
 End If
Next i
```

I have already split the code to try and see if it was limited by the number of sheets but that has made no difference (as can be see above, this only moves 4 sheets, prior to this I moved all 8 sheets at one).

Anyone know of any specific changes in the versions that would lead to this error?

EDIT:  After more experimentation I see this only occurs when I try to move a pivot table,  I can move standard data and pivot charts without a problem- but I cannto move the pivot table associated with a pivot chart without an error

Thanks

Comment: Try replacing `ActiveWorkbook.Close` with `ActiveWindow.Close`. Each open workbook is now in its own application window. In 2010 and previous versions they were all in the same application window but different workbook windows. That may not be the best way to describe it but it is pretty close. Leave `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` as it is.

Comment: Hmm, it is giving me an error stating that the "Move" method failed and then the out of memory error.  Since I am running a quad i7 with 16GB of memory I don't think there is an actual memory error...

Comment: If you installed xl2013 using defaults then you installed a 32-bit version and you could could double your memory and never receive any benefit. Take a look at [alt]+F, D, A to see what you have installed. (see [What version of Office am I using?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-version-of-Office-am-I-using-932788b8-a3ce-44bf-bb09-e334518b8b19))

Comment: It is definitely not a memory problem- with more experimentation it seems I can move anything, it is only pivot tables that seem to cause the error- pivot charts and normal sheets do not cause any errors when moved.